# Collision Detector not available in ROS2 Humble

Tags: navigation, ros2, collision

The capabilities of collision detector are available only ROS2 Iron Irwini onwards. Was wondering if ROS2 humble would ever get it? Also curious why is it not supported for ROS2 Humble, if there's any specific reason.

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/humble/nav2_collision_monitor/src

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_collision_monitor/src